# Are litotes more common in Australian English?

Tags: australian-english, litotes

Are litotes more common in Australian English, especially colloquial speech, compared to other dialects of English such as American English?

I could find on ELU a comment [stating](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108498/litotes-always-for-emphasis-used-for-non-committal-hedging-any-authoritative#comment221062_108498) that this is the case, but nothing else.

I like to think they are more common in Australian English, but that could be nationalistic bias on my part.

Comment: If you name some very specific litotes, you can do a corpora search... if you can find an Australian specific corpus.

Comment: A not entirely uninteresting question.

Comment: Do a proximity search of the corpora for "in the jaws of a salt-water croc" near "minor inconvenience" or "no big deal".

Comment: @TimRomano as crocodiles are more common in Australia than other English-speaking countries, it isn't exactly a fair comparison. Not surprisingly, the first result of a google search is for The NT News.

Comment: This is a really fascinating question. It's pretty common in the US, too, but I'm not sure how to measure it. It's also exceptionally difficult to draw the line between litotes and sarcasm, at times.

Comment: All you hafta do is get a million or two spoken Australian sentences and count the litotes, then do the same for some other place for comparison. Go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do seem more common here.  They might be part of the 'laconic' ethos. I have the sense they are less popular with the young and the media, to whom everything is 'wow', 'amazing'.  I doubt if there's any foolproof way to test your theory. I suppose you could do a google search for 'not bad','not exactly a xxx',  etc and see if you can get the source country.  There'd be a lot of subculture variations too.