# What do you call the use of a negative in order to emphasize?

Tags: terminology, negation, figures-of-speech

In particular, I was looking at this quote:

> Adam (Paradise Lost): ‘[nothing lovelier can be found / In woman, than to study household good](http://knarf.english.upenn.edu/Milton/pl9.html)’

Here's 'nothing' emphasizes 'lovelier'. Is there a term for such usage?

Comment: Inversion is for emphasis.
Normal way: They couldn't find him anywhere.
Inversion: Nowhere was he to be found.

Comment: Why do you think nothing emphasizes lovelier? Nothing is just a noun and lovelier is a comparative which is modifying the noun *nothing*. @CathyGartaganis I don't think the sentence is in inversion. It is the passive voice sentence of "They can find nothing lovelier".

Comment: @Rathony I'm sorry if I'm incorrect but I got the impression of emphasis (perhaps that's due to the passive voice). For example, it could have read 'the loveliest attribute / In women is...' without the negative 'nothing'. So, doesn't the negative emphasize?

Comment: I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question.

Comment: @Rathony  Inversion, in my opinion, is a more dramatic syntax.

Comment: @Rathony The sentence includes passive voice and inversion. Without inversion, and just passive voice, it would be: He was not to be found anywhere. Inversion uses the question form "was he".

Comment: Answered at [Litotes: Always for Emphasis? Used for Non-committal Hedging? Any Authoritative Source?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108498/litotes-always-for-emphasis-used-for-non-committal-hedging-any-authoritative)

Answer (score -1):

I think [Litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) is applicable here, with the use of the negative to emphasize the positive.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you but I can't up-vote your answer unless you further explain it. Could you add some more explanation?